# React-native app's location request times out when in background (emulator)

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get coordinates in my app.

Initially, my app allows location services as specified in AndroidManifest.xml through:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And location services works fine. Then, I go to the emulator's settings, which puts the app in the background, turn the location off, and go back to the app where it detects that location has indeed been off, so it prompts me and lets me enable location through settings again, using this code:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
    message: "<h2>Use Location ?</h2>",
    ok: 'YES',
    cancel: 'NO',
    enableHighAccuracy: false,
    showDialog: true,
    openLocationServices: true,
  }).then((success) => {
    console.log(success);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
```

And when I click 'OK' on the prompt if I should allow the app for location permission, it now says 'location request timed out'. And this is my getCurrentLocation code:

```
handleRefreshLocation() {
  console.log('refreshing location');
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      console.log('location refreshed');
      this.setState({
        long: position.coords.longitude,
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        error: null,
      }, this.updateLocation); //updateLocation is an API call to update DB
    },
    error => this.setState({ error: error.message }, this.printError),
    { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000 },
  );
}
```

I've already tried setting enableHighAccuracy to false, or removing the third argument of getCurrentPosition altogether, but nothing works. Is there any other fix to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing just the enableHighAccuracy parameter and leaving the timeout?

Also try adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```